# How to get Community to post this message in comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-user, hidden-features

I saw the Community bot had posted this comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?page=2&tab=votes#comment366550_72773):

> We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this
>   message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

The comments above it do not have any links and I am not sure what made it post that. Since the comment is still there I suppose whatever broken link caused it to be posted has not been deleted yet.

How can I get Community to post this comment?

Comment: This was an old experiment to fix broken links, it wasn't successful and since then no more automatic comments like this. The broken link is in the post itself, not comments, in the specific post you linked to it's `http:///` which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: And now you can't post such [*b0rken*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OxGmA.png) links.